# SPARQL query to get AIRLINE names from INDIA?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to get the `name` of all airlines in INDIA. My query is the following, but it is returning no results when it should. what am i doing wrong?

```
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?airline ?country WHERE {

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Airline> foaf:name  ?airline .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/India> foaf:name ?country

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "should"? How do you come to this assumption? Have you had a look at the [DBpedia page](http://dbpedia.org/page/Airline) of Airline which renders all existing facts? This is just a particular resource and not a class.

You query does what:
* he first triple pattern returns "all names of the resource Airline"
* the second triple pattern returns "all names of the resource India"
* since both triple patterns are **not connected** via a variable, it would return the cross product of both result sets

If you want to have all resources `r_i` of a particular type `:C` , which means that a triple would look like `:r rdf:type :C`, you have to use the corresponding triple pattern:

`?s rdf:type :C`

In your case, there is a class in Dbpedia for Airlines, but its URI is http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Airline , thus, the triple pattern would be

`?s rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Airline> .` and the query to get "all airlines" would be

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?airline WHERE {
 ?s a dbo:Airline .
}
```

The next step would be to find some property in DBpedia that related an Airline to a country. And that's not that simple, but you can start with the list of possible properties by executing

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT distinct ?p WHERE {
 ?s a dbo:Airline .
 ?s ?p ?o .
}
ORDER BY ?p
```

You could also check for all properties that somehow related airlines to India:

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?p (count(distinct ?s) as ?cnt) WHERE {
 ?s a dbo:Airline .
 ?s ?p dbr:India .
}
order by desc(?cnt)
```

which returns

```sql
+-------------------------------------------+-----+
|                     p                     | cnt |
+-------------------------------------------+-----+
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/headquarter   |  27 |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/headquarters  |  16 |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/destination   |   1 |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/destinations  |   1 |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/targetAirport |   1 |
| http://dbpedia.org/property/bases         |   1 |
+-------------------------------------------+-----+
```

So overall, the property `dbo:headquarter` seems to be a "good" candidates:

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?s WHERE {
 ?s a dbo:Airline .
 ?s dbo:headquarter dbr:India .
}
```

But unfortunately not all resources in DBpedia have all information since it's extracted from Wikipedia only:

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?p (count(DISTINCT ?s) as ?cnt) WHERE {
 ?s a dbo:Airline .
 ?s ?p ?o .
}
group by ?p
order by ?p
```

which means, the result of our query might be incomplete and if you know other airlines that should be in the resultset, then you have to analyze the data of the resource to discover further relationships, maybe via some intermediate hops...

An alternative is quite often to use the Wikipedia categories, although this data might contain unwanted entities:

```sql
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

SELECT ?s WHERE {    
 ?s dct:subject dbc:Airlines_of_India     
}
```